# How to add elements to a JavaScript array on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using the FullCalendar API which shows the user a calendar.  When the user clicks each date, the date pops up.  I want to add the date in a JavaScript array on each click.  As I have my code now, the date is being updated but not added to my array.

Here is what I have done:

```
select : function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#clickedDateHolder').val(date.format());
        // show modal dialog
        var input = [];
        input.push(date.format());
        $('#selectedDate').val(input);
        $('#event-modal').modal('show');
    }
```

How can I update my code in order to generate an array of all of the dates the user has clicked?

Comment: declare var input = []; outside the function otherwise it will override the existing value

Comment: you are defining the array inside of your function, therfor it is always generated again. You need to make the var input =[] outside of your function.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to declare the array of dates outside the `select` handler, ex:

```
var selectedDates = [];
$(el).fullCalendar({
    select : function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#clickedDateHolder').val(date.format());
        // show modal dialog
    //var input = [];
        selectedDates.push(date.format());
        $('#selectedDate').val(input);
        $('#event-modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```